# how can I update a file in tarball?

Tags: go, tar

How can I update a file in tarball with Go?

I can only find some way to append file into a tar file like this:

```
file, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
if _, err = file.Seek(-1024, os.SEEK_END); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
if err != nil { return err }
defer file.Close()
tw := tar.NewWriter(file)
hdr := &tar.Header{
    Name: "manifest.json",
    Mode: 0644,
    Size: int64(len(content)),
}
if err := tw.WriteHeader(hdr); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if _, err := tw.Write(content); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if err := tw.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

---

After finding solutions by google ,it seemed I have some commands like `tar uvf ...` or try to extract the tarball and make a new one by golang or command `tar`.

As tar document says , command `tar uf` can update a file in tar ball directly, but after using `tar uvf` , I found a very interesting thing like below:

a.tar is a docker image made by `docker image save`

I want to change manifest.json file in thie docker image tarball by `tar uvf a.tar manifest.json`
before update, the content of tarball seems OK.

```
[root@master1 a]# ls
a.tar
[root@master1 a]# tar xf a.tar 
tar: manifest.json: implausibly old time stamp 1970-01-01 08:00:00
tar: repositories: implausibly old time stamp 1970-01-01 08:00:00
[root@master1 a]# ls
2080c332033e330242f9ea2043e18c7ea98de2ee1b1b3921b1a33bcb84ac4cd5
2acf0fc34f8cc199bde6f74a7d85382461ff69cf4618e5964e7e1d19d0fe1d5c
3962220e6895f5a8c88034ae1bc7926b9bb40ecdc441196cd01c7cf36e36b7db.json
a7d478578679c443a1d4e695154dbbe8cad5525ac46fa80e925c2a080d0b620f
a.tar
c2103589e99f907333422ae78702360ad258a8f0366c20e341c9e0c53743e78a.json
da70bf0a87b384edc6cfc5cff3a33ba087de7b81f914df73181bfc2869314ebb
manifest.json
repositories
```

then I try to update manifest.json by `tar uvf a.tar manifest.json`

```
[root@master1 b]# ls
a.tar
[root@master1 b]# tar xf a.tar 
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
[root@master1 b]# ls -al
total 65972
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Apr 26 15:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Apr 26 15:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Sep 10  2019 2080c332033e330242f9ea2043e18c7ea98de2ee1b1b3921b1a33bcb84ac4cd5
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 31  2019 2acf0fc34f8cc199bde6f74a7d85382461ff69cf4618e5964e7e1d19d0fe1d5c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2429 Dec 31  2019 3962220e6895f5a8c88034ae1bc7926b9bb40ecdc441196cd01c7cf36e36b7db.json
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 31  2019 a7d478578679c443a1d4e695154dbbe8cad5525ac46fa80e925c2a080d0b620f
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67517440 Apr 26 15:28 a.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2467 Sep 10  2019 c2103589e99f907333422ae78702360ad258a8f0366c20e341c9e0c53743e78a.json
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Sep 10  2019 da70bf0a87b384edc6cfc5cff3a33ba087de7b81f914df73181bfc2869314ebb
```

As you can see, `manifest.json` and `repositories` disappeared . And sometimes , there will be a `var` directory.  This is very strange .

Thanks a lot if someone can tell me why.

---

After trying use command `7za d` and `7za a`, I change a file in a tarball successfully .

Comment: I don't think you can. I believe the problem is the same as changing a line in a file. You have to rewrite the whole file.

Comment: You cannot update a file in a tar file.  (Well, technically, you might be able to if it was exactly the same size).  You have to re-write the tar file with the new contents.  This makes sense intuitively when you consider that TAR stands for Tape ARchive... it's a format designed for storage on magnetic tapes, where there is no possibility of random access.

Comment: Ah, in my sitiuation , it's ok to change tar file size .Actually what I want to do is doing same work like `tar uvf` supposed to do .

Comment: I believe tar u appends data to the archive,  I don't think it removes old versions of anything